# This node is not attached to the dom heamsnapshot memory leak or not?

Tags: html, angularjs, memory-leaks

I have an application in which the size of objects increases when we use the site. I am trying to find memory leaks in my application and found some things that causes memory leaks in javascript. Well, we are using angularjs. Now, i just looked something in IE heap snapshot but i am not sure it causes memory leak or not? 
Whenever i click on some specific tab, i see same HTML in heap snapshot and IE says "This Node Is Not Attached To The DOM". Below is the image:
[image]

These nodes increases whenever i exit from specific page. Is this causes memory leak? If it is the problem then how i can resolve this?